# Typescript/Angular : Close a Tab opened somewhere else in Session

Tags: angular, typescript

Am Looking to see how I can close a Tab in an angular session which was opened somewhere else in the same session.

For example:

***In Component A***

`this.window = this.windowToken.open('Some URL', 'Some Tab Name', 'Some Tab Params');`

***In Some RouteGuard***

`// Retrieve this.window Object
this.window.close()`

I tried saving this in local/session storage but I dont think you can save Window Objects there:
`localStorage.setItem('Window', this.window); -- this throws an error. expects (string, string)`

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Simplest way to do this is using service.

```
export class TabService {
  tab;

  constructor() { }

  openTab(url, spec) {
    this.tab = window.open(url, spec);
  }

  closeTab() {
    if(this.tab) {
      this.tab.close();
    }
  }

}
```

[Live demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvnxks?embed=1&file=src/app/tab-open-close/tab-open-close.component.ts)

Let me know if any changes needs to be done.